# Delete rows in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a problem, I have in SAS Guide a table with two columns, column1 and column2, I need to do the following, take the value of the first record in column2 and search for it in all the records in column1, once found delete them. This must be repeated for each value in column2 doing it each time on the table with deleted records. All values are text type. I have tried doing this with an array that is updated after each iteration, but it does not work 100% of the time.

I have tried doing this with an array that is updated after each iteration, but it does not work 100% of the time.

Comment: Delete them as in delete the row or set the value in column1 missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a SQL query to select the rows that meet your criteria.

Example:

```
data have;
  call streaminit(20230427);
  do row = 1 to 30;
    x = 43 + rand('integer',1, 12);
    y = 45 + rand('integer',1, 10);
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sql;
  create table want(label='no x is in y') as
  select * from have
  where x not in (select y from have);
```